# Derivation of the batch backpropagation algorithm

Tags: neural-networks

How is the backpropagation algorithm derived when thinking about the batch version? Or is it first derived for stochastic (one instance from dataset) and then the formulas are generalized?

I just don't understand how can one compute the derivative of the cost function with respect to the net input [in the batch version], because there are n net inputs for a specific neuron.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're talking about a batch backpropagation algorithm I am unaware of (if so, post a link), I think you may be getting confused.

Conceptually there are two different parts: backprogation and the mini-batch gradient descent. For each element of the the batch $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n\}$, you backpropagate the error for each individual example $x_i$ and you get gradients for each weight for each example. At the end of each batch, you determine the weight adjustment by averaging over the gradients and use mini-batch gradient descent (for instance) to determine the optimal direction to adjust your weights based on the average weights.

Comment: On the Web, I saw that the algorithm is derived using a cost function that includes just one training example. And then comes the generalization. When thinking about GD, should we obtain the update rules only for an instance and then generalize? Or should we start with a cost function including all the training instances?

Comment: When you say "the algorithm is derived [...]", do you mean stochastic gradient descent or backpropagation?  There are distinct versions of gradient descent talked about in relation to training neural networks: the original gradient descent algorithm, stochastic gradient descent, and mini-batch gradient descent. Gradient descent require the computation of gradients for the whole dataset, stochastic gradient descent require only a single datapoint, and mini-batch gradient descent uses a small number of examples (say 32). Above, I am talking about mini-batch gradient descent which is most common.